# Devices not working properly on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop

Tags: 14.04, wireless, usb, cd, devices

None of the devices are working on my ubuntu14.04 desktop all of a sudden. Wifi shows: device not ready. USB has no responds, neither does the CDROM. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Since none of the devices work on that desktop, it's very hard for me to paste the results of some command from it to here, so I will just briefly describe the results of `lsusb` and lsblk below:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 002 Device 003: Logitech mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: Intel integrated rate matching hub
Bus 002 Device 001: Linux 2.0 root Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: Toshiba Kinston Data Traveler(USB) 
Bus 001 Device 002: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsblk:`

```
sda        disk 
 - sda1    part /
 - sda2    part
 - sda5    part [SWAP]
sdb        disk
 - sdb1    part
sr0        rom
loop0      loop
 - docker  dm
loop1      loop
 - docker
```

Comment: Please run commands 'lsusb' and 'lsblk' and show us the results. Oh, and did you reboot?

Comment: Yes I rebooted like 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. There was something wrong with an earlier software update which exited unexpectedly. Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` solved this problem and now devices are working again.